# Trouble with MATLAB triple integral

Tags: matlab, convolution, gaussian, integral

The equation I am trying to evaluate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0HxL.jpg

I'm attempting to evaluate this integral (and equation) where 'a' and 'x' are just inputs, and x' is (x,y,z). also: x will have the form [a,b,c]. In my 'int_func' below, I have taken the dot product of the transpose and the original, to yield the ^2 power that is observable below, for example in: (X(:,1)-x).^2

*The code I have so far is:*

```matlab
int_func = @(x,y,z) func([x,y,z]).*exp((-3/(2*a^2)).*((X(:,1)-x).^2 + (X(:,2)-y).^2 + (X(:,3)-z).^2));

val = integral3(int_func,-inf,inf,-inf,inf,-inf,inf);
disp(val * (3/(2*pi*a^2))^(3/2));
```

*where:*

```matlab
X = [0, 0, 0];

a = 1;
```

With this code, I should be getting an answer of **0.0370, but instead, I am getting 0.5556.**

Can someone suggest another form of evaluating this integral or spot what is wrong with what I have listed?

Comment: Your code does not run. Please post a reproducible example and also use the proper formatting to your questions (eg. format your code as a code block) to get more people interested.

Comment: I've posted an updated version here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213290/matlab-triple-integral-evaluation

Comment: I meant to edit your existing post, not create a new one, not sure if you deleted the other post or was closed by moderators but it's better that way. I try executing your code, first defining `X = [0,0,0];`,`a=1` and then your "The code I have so far is". This produces an error as your `func` inside the `int_func` is undefined, and I cannot reproduce your scenario.